# I am trying to install "clustergrammer_widget" in order to create an advanced heatmap. The following error messages will show the trouble I'm having

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, heatmap, failed-installation

I have followed all of the Clustergrammer-Widget documentation for installation and use in a Jupyter Notebook (managed through Anaconda) as precisely as possible and the following 2 clues seem to point to an error in installation. This is the link to the documentation:

https://clustergrammer.readthedocs.io/clustergrammer_widget.html#clustergrammer-widget

These are the installation instructions which I have ran in my Conda environment:

pip install --upgrade clustergrammer_widget
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix clustergrammer_widget

The text below demonstrates that all of the above instructions seem to run fine except for the very last item which reads "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'class_traits'"

```
(obb) C:\Users\richa>pip install clustergrammer_widget
Requirement already satisfied: clustergrammer_widget in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (1.13.3)
Requirement already satisfied: ipywidgets>=5.1.5 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from clustergrammer_widget) (8.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: widgetsnbextension~=4.0 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (4.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab-widgets~=3.0 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (3.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel>=4.5.1 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (6.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=6.1.0 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (8.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.3.1 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (5.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nest-asyncio in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (1.5.6)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=6.1.12 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (7.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib-inline>=0.1 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (0.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: debugpy>=1.0 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (1.6.6)
Requirement already satisfied: comm>=0.1.1 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (5.9.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (25.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=6.1 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=6.1.0->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.16 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=6.1.0->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<3.1.0,>3.0.1 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=6.1.0->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (3.0.36)
Requirement already satisfied: stack-data in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=6.1.0->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments>=2.4.0 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=6.1.0->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (2.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=6.1.0->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=6.1.0->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=6.1.0->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from jedi>=0.16->ipython>=6.1.0->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=6.1.12->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core>=4.9.2 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=6.1.12->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=6.1.12->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<3.1.0,>3.0.1->ipython>=6.1.0->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (0.2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: executing in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from stack-data->ipython>=6.1.0->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: asttokens in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from stack-data->ipython>=6.1.0->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (2.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pure-eval in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from stack-data->ipython>=6.1.0->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs>=2.5 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-core>=4.9.2->jupyter-client>=6.1.12->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (2.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=1.0 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from jupyter-core>=4.9.2->jupyter-client>=6.1.12->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (305.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->jupyter-client>=6.1.12->ipykernel>=4.5.1->ipywidgets>=5.1.5->clustergrammer_widget) (1.16.0)

(obb) C:\Users\richa>jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...
      - Validating: ok

(obb) C:\Users\richa>jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix clustergrammer_widget
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\Scripts\jupyter-nbextension-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 276, in launch_instance
    return super().launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\Users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 972, in start
    super().start()
  File "C:\Users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 265, in start
    self.subapp.start()
  File "C:\Users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 882, in start
    self.toggle_nbextension_python(self.extra_args[0])
  File "C:\Users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 855, in toggle_nbextension_python
    return toggle(module,
  File "C:\Users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 470, in enable_nbextension_python
    return _set_nbextension_state_python(True, module, user, sys_prefix,
  File "C:\Users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 368, in _set_nbextension_state_python
    m, nbexts = _get_nbextension_metadata(module)
  File "C:\Users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 1107, in _get_nbextension_metadata
    m = import_item(module)
  File "C:\Users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages\traitlets\utils\importstring.py", line 38, in import_item
    return __import__(parts[0])
  File "C:\Users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages\clustergrammer_widget\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .example import *
  File "C:\Users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages\clustergrammer_widget\example.py", line 10, in <module>
    @widgets.register('hello.Hello')
  File "C:\Users\richa\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages\ipywidgets\widgets\widget.py", line 279, in register
    w = widget.class_traits()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'class_traits'

(obb) C:\Users\richa>
```

I was expecting the installation to be clean with no errors, etc.  Beyond that, when I tried to run example code in the Jupyter notebook I get the following results.  My only take is that I need to resolve the installation issue first.

```
# import widget classes and instantiate Network instance

from clustergrammer_widget import *
net = Network(clustergrammer_widget)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [22], line 2
      1 # import widget classes and instantiate Network instance
----> 2 from clustergrammer_widget import *
      3 net = Network(clustergrammer_widget)

File ~\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages\clustergrammer_widget\__init__.py:3
      1 from ._version import version_info, __version__
----> 3 from .example import *
      5 def _jupyter_nbextension_paths():
      6     return [{
      7         'section': 'notebook',
      8         'src': 'static',
      9         'dest': 'clustergrammer_widget',
     10         'require': 'clustergrammer_widget/extension'
     11     }]

File ~\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages\clustergrammer_widget\example.py:10
      6 Network = clustergrammer.Network
      8 # version 1.13.3
---> 10 @widgets.register('hello.Hello')
     11 class clustergrammer_widget(widgets.DOMWidget):
     12     """
     13     Clustergrammer-Widget generates an interactive heatmap in the Jupyter
     14     notebook. Clustergrammer-Widget inherits from Clustergrammer.py which can
     15     be used to load data, filter, normalize, and cluster.
     16     """
     17     _view_name = Unicode('hello_view').tag(sync=True)

File ~\miniconda3\envs\obb\lib\site-packages\ipywidgets\widgets\widget.py:279, in register(widget)
    277 def register(widget):
    278     """A decorator registering a widget class in the widget registry."""
--> 279     w = widget.class_traits()
    280     _registry.register(w['_model_module'].default_value,
    281                                  w['_model_module_version'].default_value,
    282                                  w['_model_name'].default_value,
   (...)
    285                                  w['_view_name'].default_value,
    286                                  widget)
    287     return widget

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'class_traits'
```

Comment: The top of what you link (https://clustergrammer.readthedocs.io/clustergrammer_widget.html#clustergrammer-widget) to says to use Clustergrammer2. Have you tried installing that instead following [the recommendations](https://github.com/ismms-himc/clustergrammer2#installation)?

Comment: I had missed that comment and urging in the documentation.  I just walked thru all of the steps I could follow on installation in a different environment and it installed clean.  Having said that, I'm a little lost where to go next with how to proceed from there with my project.  The clustergrammer-widget step-by-step were more straightforward!  I'll keep working on it but if you have any basic thoughts/questions/suggested steps it would be much appreciated! Thanks for responding!

Comment: Because the note about Clustergrammer2 [here](https://clustergrammer.readthedocs.io/clustergrammer2.html#clustergrammer2), elsewhere in the documentation, still points to the same 'Case Studies and Turorials' link, I think it largely plugs right in as an upgraded version. One resource I can point you at that may help also is [here at the Clustergrammer2 repo](https://github.com/ismms-himc/clustergrammer2#basic-example-of-running-clustergrammer2-on-mybinder) is a 'launch' badge (blue on on on the left). If you click on that it will launch a session with stuff already installed & working. ...

Comment: <continued>. Importantly, starte [with that one](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/ismms-himc/clustergrammer2-notebooks/master?filepath=notebooks%2F1.0_Running_Clustergrammer2.ipynb) and not the one above because currently the one above starts in JupyterLab and you have to switch to the classic notebook where at least in these sessions, things work better than JuptyerLab. (Switch is easy though. Go to 'Help' in menubar above the JupyterLAb interface and then select 'Launch Classic Notebook' from under 'Help'.) Slowly, step through running each of the first three cells of that notebook ...

Comment: <continued> '1.0' that comes up. That should give you an example of the widget working. Continue on working through that notebook. When you want to go to the other notebooks, go to the URL bar in your browser and delete the text `notebooks/notebooks/1.0_Running_Clustergrammer2.ipynb` at the end of the address and replace it with `tree`. Then lick to go into the 'notebooks' folder from this navigator dashboard page. Other notebooks will be listed there to work through. I know it seems a bit clunky but once you get through to that page listing the notebooks, the new notebooks you click on ...

Comment: Awesome sir!  As a relative newbie all of these various pathways and steps are a labyrinth to me but I've survived in my career and personal pursuits through perseverance and not-afraid-to-ask-for-help... I'll follow this advice and report back!

Comment: <continued>  will probably open in a new tab so you only have to get there once. Part of the clunkiness derives from the fact that settings in the repo where the session launches from don't make it work well in JupyterLab which is now the default in MyBinder sessions. Being the default, the interface is set up to try to take you to JupyterLab now, and you want to avoid that so you can use the widget in those sessions. (In theory it should work in current JupyterLab, but I haven't found an example set up so it works via MyBinder. )

Comment: I understand. Part of the labyrinth can come from things breaking here and there. MyBinder alone relies on a lot of moving pieces working and so it can be sensitive. Then there is the complexity of a complex package like clustergrammer and everything it is dependent on. When you are learning, these small hurdles can seem like massive roadblocks.

Comment: Hi Wayne,  I wanted to report back that I ran out of time on this but picked it up again this morning.  Unfortunately I've tried to run the Binder versions on 2 different machines but they keep failing.  I did get it to work the first time when you posted it however.  It's probably just a server issue and I can try again.  In any event I intend to keep at this until successful and will keep you posted.  Appreciate help again.  In the meantime, I know what may eventually help is a little more detail about how to get from the Binder versions to my Jupyter notebook local hard drive version.

Comment: I followed your directions above conceptually but as I perused the details it wasn't clear in my head how I'd migrate.  If you'd prefer, just hold off until I run into a specific roadblock with your "roadmap" above.  Thanks again!!

Comment: Sorry, I think [MyBinder has undergone a significant upgrade](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/mybinder-org-and-repo2docker-updates/18333) in the last few days. I think I'm seeing some other related hiccups, too. I'm seeing these pages not build now myself. Sorry.  I think it is because MyBinder now uses Python 3.10 by default. I can test but I'm in no rush myself right now. Sorry. If clustergrammar 2 is working on your local system you can indeed get the notebooks and work through them there. Is that the case? I think you said it was. So I'll advise how to get the content next.

Comment: If you wanted to get the notebooks I've been advising you to run so you can run them on your own machine, go [here to the Clustergrammer2 Notebooks repository site](https://github.com/ismms-himc/clustergrammer2-notebooks). (Since you asked about getting content from GitHub, I'm going to assume you aren't using `git` and advise a more traditional download route.) In the upper right side, just above the listing of the files and folders present at that repository should be a bright green button labeled '<> Code'. Click the green button to toggge the drodpdown. At the bottom, should be a choice...

Comment: <continued> that says 'Download Zip'. Click on that and save the zip file to your local system system. Hopefully on your system you already have something that will unpack that type of archive. Once downloaded, double-click on it to unpack it or look up how you'd extract a zip archive on your system. I suspect it will unpack everything in one directory. Put that directory in your system's file hierarchy **below** where you've been running notebooks. If you do that right, you should be able to open your Jupyter and open the notebooks in 'notebooks' directory inside what you unpacked. ...

Comment: <continued> The notebooks should work if your system has the package installed and you keep the hierarchy correct because I think the notebooks will refer to things in the `data` directory inside the overarching directory your unpacked from your download. The relative relationship of all the directories needs to be intact for the notebooks to continue to access the associated files they need, such as `data`. So now you should be able to run the code in the notebooks on your own system and get an idea of how things work.